# Is there a way to change the QGIS default CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm working in a UTM projection and bringing in dxf layers from a different program.  The dxf files are all in the correct UTM coordinates already, but when I bring them in I need to change the CRS to UTM 17N instead of WGS 84.  Is there a way to change this default CRS?

Working in QGIS 2.6 Brighton

Comment: how do you change default projection in qgis?

Comment: @Liberty it can be changed in the same screen.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `Settings -> Options -> CRS` tab, you can select to `Prompt for CRS` for new layers.

That should avoid the automatic assigning of wrong projections.

Comment: Perfect! And the option is there as well to change the default CRS if I know everything I'll be bringing in for that project will be UTM 17N - no prompt necessary